# Talend issue while copying local files to HDFS

Tags: talend, hortonworks-sandbox

Hi I want to know how to copy files to HDFS from source file system(Local File system),if source file already copied to HDFS,then how to eliminate or ignore that file to copy again in HDFS using Talend.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

To copy files from local file system to the HDFS, you need to use [tHDFSPut](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuideFall1EN/tHDFSPut) components if you have Talend for big data. If you use Talend for data integration you can easily use [tSystem](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/19.4+tSystem) component with the right [command](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put).

To avoid duplicated files, you need to create a table in a RDBMS and keep track of all copied files. Each time the job start copying file, it should check if it already exists in the table.